# Define a variable getting the value from a matplotlib scatter coordinate

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates

I am trying to use a x coordinate of a point, as x coordinate of the first point for a line. I change this value every day, and I would like it to change automatically for the line. Any suggestions?

```
#This is the point. I am interested in get the first value (39), to be automatically copied in the plt.plot (in this case a copied manually de value 39)    
plt.scatter(39, 78, color = "yellow", alpha = .5, s = 80, zorder = 2, marker = "*") 
        
#Proiezione retta
plt.plot((delta.days, 39), (mm7g[-1], 78), zorder = 0, color = 'w', linewidth = 0.4, ls = '--')   #
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood the problem correctly, but why don't you just define the value x  as a variable (`x = 39`) and use that variable in both calls (`plt.scatter(x, 78...`/ `plt.plot((delta.days, x)...`,, modifying the value of the variable will apply to both.

Comment: You did understand. And I think your solution is absolutely valid. Thank you.